# Assign AJAX data to class variable in AngularJS2

Tags: asynchronous, angular, angular-http

I am doing the following code and unable to figure out that why the data I am obtaining through AJAX is not being assigned to the class variable which is `this.users`

**Code Snippet**

```
getUsers() {
     this.http.get('/app/actions.php?method=users')
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        res => { this.users = res}, // If I console 'res' here it prints as expected
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('done')
    );
    console.log(this.users) // Printing 'undefined'
    return this.users;
  }
```

Any help will be much appreciated. This (http://prntscr.com/cal2l1) is link to my console output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason for Problem**

Well, it was really a silly mistake which I was making here. Since, `getUsers()` was being called after the DOM was loaded so it was assigning the value to class variable which is `this.users` after loading of DOM which restricted my page to load the required values at page loading stage (not after page loading).

**Solution**

Angular2 comes with a hook called `OnInit` or `ngOnInit()`. I was supposed to call the function in this event as follows.

```
getUsers() {
     this.http.get('/app/actions.php?method=users')
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        res => { this.users = res}, 
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('done')
    );
    console.log(this.users)
    return this.users;
  }

ngOnInit() {
    getUsers();
  }
```

**Documentaion of OnInit:** https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnInit-class.html

Also the following documentation came up as a helping tool:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

Answer (score 1):

It is an asynchronous call, so you don't fetch data right away. However, if you `setTimeout()` on `console.log()`, it will be printed correctly because printing will occur after the data is fetched:

```
getUsers() {
    this.http.get('/app/actions.php?method=users')
    .map((res:Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe(
    res => { this.users = res}, // If I console 'res' here it prints as expected
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.log('done')
);

setTimeout(() => {
console.log(this.users) // Printing 'undefined'
}, 1000);
return this.users;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but this is not where I am mistaking. Your solution is still not assigning the value to `this.users` before it is being returned.

Comment: @AshwaniGoyal Just change value for `setTimeout()` from 1000 to 5000 for example, I guarantee it will work.